# Hamiltonian path in dynamic graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reductions

Given an undirected Graph. I want to find a hamiltonian path with no restriction to starting or ending vertices. I know there are some smart algorithms for solving that.
Now let's make things interesting: sometimes, when I arrive at a vertex, the edges connected to that vertex change. I.e. some will be removed, others appear. It is only depending on the edge I used before which egdes will change.
That means, if I go from vertex $v_1$ to $v_x$, edges connected to $v_x$ will change in the way $b_{1,x}$. if I arrived $v_x$ via $v_2$, edges will change in the way $b_{2,x}$ and so on.

I am looking for a efficient algorithm telling me if there is a hamiltonian path and output that if so. Has anybody ideas on how to approach that? Or has anyone an idea if this can be transformed into another better known problem?

Comment: Could you name any of the *smart* algorithms for the Hamiltonian Path problem?

Comment: [This page](http://www.flinders.edu.au/science_engineering/csem/research/programs/flinders-hamiltonian-cycle-project/) presents some good heuristics. Particularly, I waas pretty impressed by their snakes-and-ladders heuristic, which you can try out via an applet. But don't attach too much importance to that sentence. It's not the point here ;-)

Comment: Seems to me that you can blow up the graph by a factor of $n$, direct it, and then search for directed $n$-cycles.

Comment: See also the comments in http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10482/755