# The name of "finding the path of a graph that is a variant of hamiltonian path"

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Suppose that there is some graph, with $n$ vertexes. We wish to find the hamiltonian path, but we make the graph being searched a little different. There is a person A that travels each (undirected) edge that connects one vertex to the other vertex. But after the person crosses the edge, how edges connect pairs of vertexes change. (So, for example, before one crossed(traveled) one edge, there was an edge that connects vertex A to vertex B, but after some edge is crossed, there may no longer be the edge that connects vertex A to vertex B.) How the graph changes depends only on the order of the path being crossed - so, if he is on the third vertex in the path he chose, regardless of what path is, how the graph changes only depend on the fact that it is third vertex. Every change is known and inserted as input. Then we compute hamiltonian path.

We can replace human with machine.

So, what would be the name of finding hampath in such graph? And what complexity class would this be in?

I tried to search this in my complexity textbook, but failed miserably - so I wonder if this even has a name.

Comment: oh yes it seems... but complexity class? Which complexity class would this be in?

Comment: The problem is still NP-complete because it is a generalization of the Hamiltonian path (just pick an instance where there are no "changes"). If you allow multiple node/edge traversals and some nodes act like a "switch" then the problem becomes PSPACE complete (the first reference that comes to my mind is Viglietta's framework 
[Gaming is a hard job, but someone has to do it!](http://www.di.unipi.it/~vigliett/files/papers/gaming.pdf) ).

Comment: In its current guise where every change is known, the problem is probably NP-complete -- the reduction shown by vor works. However, I actually think this problem is almost certainly PSPACE-complete if the changes are "random" or unknown. In that form, it reminds me of the Canadian travellers problem (finding the shortest path in a graph where edges are revealed only if one of their nodes is visited).